# Is there a way to insert the value of the foreign key value from the primary key of another table when sending a payload in postman?

Tags: java, jpa

**`Author.java`:**

```
package com.abc.entity;    

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false, name="id")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="author_seq", name="a_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="a_seq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="first_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "First Name is required")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    @NotNull(message = "Last Name is required")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    @NotNull(message="email cannot be null")
    @Email
    @Pattern(regexp="[A-Za-z0-9._%-+]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message="Password")
    @Size(min=8, max=16, message="Password must be >= 8 and <=16 ")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(/*orphanRemoval = true,*/
            //mappedBy="author",
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();



    /**
     * Adding a book and in turn setting it author to this object
     * @param book
     */
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
        book.setAuthor(this);
    }

    /**
     * Removing a book from the author
     * @param book
     */
    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        books.remove(book);
        book.setAuthor(null);
    }
}
```

**`Book.java`:**

```
package com.abc.entity;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false, name="id")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="book_seq", name="b_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="b_seq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="isbn")
    @NotNull(message = "isbn is required")
    //@Size(min=8, max=8, message="isbn must be = 8 numbers")
    private Long isbn;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="title")
    @NotNull(message = "Title is required")
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="edition")
    @NotBlank(message = "Edition is required")
    private String edition;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="price")
    @NotNull(message = "Price is required")
    private Double price;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="date_published")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$", message = "Must be formatted MM/YY")
    private String datePublished;

    //@ForeignKey(name="FK_COUNTRY")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id")//, referencedColumnName="id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Author author;
}
```

I think that the foreign key column in the `book` table will be inserted with the primary key of the `author` table.

However, `null` is inserted if I removed the `referencedColumnName` attribute that points to the primary key of the author.

When I add `referencedColumnName` attribute, I have an error indicating `null` cannot be inserted into the foreign key column of the `book` table.

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SPRING"."BOOK"."AUTHOR_ID")
```

I created two entities.

1. An `Author` (who can have/write many books) [`OneToMany`]
2. A `Book` that can belong to only one author [`ManyToOne`]

When I send a payload in Postman to test `@PostMapping` that inserts an `author`, the foreign key in `book` table (`author_id`) that should refer to the primary key of `author` table (`id`) is inserted with a `null` and not the value of the `author`'s primary key.

When I add `referencedColumnName`, it throws an exception indicating that `null` cannot be inserted into `book.author_id`.

I have tried:

1. using the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation
2. `referencedColumnName` attribute

Comment: I think first you must persist the author then you persist the book, you did it like that? or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I sent this payload
{
 "firstName" : "Bais",
 "lastName" : "Cham",
 "email" : "baischam1@abc.com",
 "password" : "secretPassword",
 "books" : 
 [
  {
  
   "isbn" : "12377665",
   "title" : "Living Peacefully",
   "edition" : "first",
   "price" : "25.45",
   "datePublished" : "02/23"
  }
 ]
}

all the fields in the author table are inserted
all the fields in the book table are inserted with the correct value except the foreign key. I think it should have the value of the primary key, but it has null.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding two annotations: JsonManageReference and JsonBackReference.

@JsonManageReference on the field
private List books inside the Author class

and 
@JsonBackReference on the field
private Author author inside the Book class